# Is it possible to generate IdTokens for AzureAd for writing End To End Tests with Protractor?

Tags: oauth, protractor, azure-active-directory, openid, end-to-end

We're writing end to end tests with protractor for an application written in Angular. The app authenticates via Azure AD using the ADAL library.

Currently we click through the AzureAd sign in process using WebDriver before the tests start, but this is fragile. We had issues with the Microsoft password login screen not loading at all. Also the login process locally can get complicated because it takes our Windows credentials sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

Looking for alternatives, is it possible to generate either:

- An idtoken in the protractor start up process (onPrepare) through some node library (like passport?) from Azure Ad directly? That I can later set for the tests to use.
- Some sort of forever living static bearer idtoken that the e2e tests read from a config file?

Is there any other approach I could be missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ROPC flow to acquire tokens for tests.
This is one of the cases where using this flow can be ok in my opinion.
Using it to bypass the login screen in a normal app is not okay.
It also doesn't work with all kinds of users, federated users can sometimes work, depending on how it's setup.

Here is what I've used:

```
// _authority = e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.com
string tokenUrl = _authority + "oauth2/v2.0/token";
var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl)
{
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "password",
        ["client_id"] = settings.ClientId, // client id for your app
        ["client_secret"] = settings.ClientSecret, // client secret for your app
        ["scope"] = $"openid profile {_resourceUri}/.default", // here you define what you want tokens for
        ["username"] = settings.UserName,
        ["password"] = settings.Password
    })
};

HttpResponseMessage res = await _client.SendAsync(req);

string json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
AadTokenResponse tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AadTokenResponse>(json);
// tokenResponse.IdToken contains the ID token

// The AadTokenResponse class:
class AadTokenResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id_token")]
    public string IdToken { get; set; }
}
```

The scope is where you must specify at least the `openid` scope in order to get an ID token.
Here I have also specified an API app ID URI + "/.default" to get an access token for an API.
You can keep the scope as `openid profile` if you only need the id token.

Keep in mind that you will then need to secure app credentials and user credentials in your test configuration.
Also, I recommend that these credentials are *not* for a production environment.
You may need to create cloud-only user accounts for them to work properly.
Also the user accounts cannot have MFA enabled.
If their password expires, you'll need to set a new password and update your test config.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check if there is some way to do it from node.

Comment: You should be able to, you'll need to translate the C# for the HTTP call :)